# How to create a window on Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, com, bho

I try to create a window on Internet Explorer,just like this:
[I wrote this with C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMQzi.jpg)

But I do not know how to design a dialog with MFC,I want to develop this program with c#.

I already know that using BHO can do this work.Here is the core code:

```
public int SetSite(object site)
{

    if (site != null)
    {
        webBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)site;
        webBrowser.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
    }
    else
    {
        webBrowser.DocumentComplete -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
        webBrowser = null;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

onDocumentComplete :

```
    SHDocVw.WebBrowser webBrowser;

    public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        Form form1 = new Form();
        IntPtr p = new IntPtr(webBrowser.HWND);
        Control con = Control.FromHandle(p);
        con.Controls.Add(form1);
    }
```

But this do not work.Please tell me waht's wrong with my code and how can I do this work.Thank you.